# I just want to be able to remove the "Filters" button from Catalog > Products page

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, phtml

I just have this button
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIFgn.png) in the Catalog > Products page

I just want to be able to remove/hide it programmatically.

Comment: Can you please provide more infomation? as from what you have put you want to remove the filters from the product grid within the admin

Comment: That's correct, I just want to hide/remove the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rewrite product_listing.xml.

path:`vendor/magento/modulecatalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`

remove code in the product_listing.xml:

```
<filters name="listing_filters">
            <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                    <caption translate="true">All Store Views</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                    <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
 </filters>
```

Comment: never edit vendor, as next time you run composer update the file changed will be reveted. if your going to impliment this id suggest you create a module under app and do it that way

Comment: @DavaGordon What would be your solution for doing this without modifying the vendor ?  I have a similar issue but can't find a way threw : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/353606/how-to-override-an-existing-ui-component-filtersearch

Answer (score -1):

Search for this button code in phtml , where it is rendered.
Create simple module:
1.add to system.xml select with yes /no.
2.create helper, that will check this setting.
3.add your helper to phtml file.
4. Add a construction if with checking your value from admin configuration ( this is doing by helper).
And check - if in admin it is value = 1(yes,hide it) , u should not render it.